# Show personal info in personal folder

Tags: plone

We know that /author/user can show personal information at all users.
Well in my case, each user has a personal folder whitin contents.
My goal is to show the info in /author/user, when an user visit the personal folder of each user. This info must be show first, with the option "select a content item as default view".
I've created a link to /author/user and option "select a content item as default view".
The problem is that the user are redirected to /author/user and cannot navigate in the personal folder.
Is there a trick that solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of realizing this with a content item as default view you could just register a new view for folders, being a customized copy of author.pt.

Answer (score 0):

you've two problems: change the default view for user folder (only for those) and creating a new view.

Use the code from author.cpt to make a new skin cpt (or just a .pt removing the feedback form if you don't need it), and just change:

```
author python:(len(request.traverse_subpath) > 0 and url_unquote_plus(request.traverse_subpath[0])) or request.get('author', None);
```

to something that grab the user from username or /Members/<> path. Then copy the Folder type in portal_types to a new id (New User Folder or similar), assign this as a default folder in portal_membership for the user and in portal_types -> New User Folder and assign it as default view.

Then you've to migrate all users home folder to this new folder type.

An alternative is to have an index_html script that loads the alternative view, maybe just calling author.cpt with the author parameter in the request:

```
context.author(author=<<this folder author>>)
```

where <> is obtained as before. You can add this index_html following this hint on doing things after the user log in:

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sessions/login.html#post-login-actions